# Firebase Functions won't read document on Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi I'm trying to read a users document stored on Firestore using Firebase Functions. Each user has a unique document with extra data that cannot be stored on Firebase Auth. The document name is the user UID.
But I can't access the doc when I'm trying to read it on my callable function.

Code to create doc when user is created:

```
exports.createdacc = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {

console.log('User created', user.phoneNumber);
return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
    number: user.phoneNumber,
    verified: false,
});
```

});

Callable function to read that doc so I can make some decisions

```
exports.checkVerification = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
if (!context.auth){
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated');
}
console.log('user is ', context.auth.uid);
const user = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.auth.uid);
user.get().then(doc => {    
    //temp code -- Not working 
    console.log('data read');
    if (doc.get().verified){
        console.log('verified');
    } else {
        console.log('not verified');
    }
    return "success";
}).catch(error => {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal');
});
});
```

Why cant I read the doc? Nothing inside there executes.

Comment: Did you check whether doc is created or not in firebase console

Comment: @development-ninja yes the doc exists. I can even access it from android using the library.

Comment: Ok and did you get correct context.auth.uid inside callable function?

Comment: @development-ninja yep the uids match.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use data() at callback of user.get()

```
user.get().then(doc => {    
    //you get user doc value by using data()
    const userData = doc.data();
    // then you can use all properties from userData
    const verified = userData.verified;
});
```

Comment: I found the issue. If I use the context.auth.uid it does not work. But if I directly put the string value inside the brackets it works. Problem is that they are both identical.

Comment: Good solution, nice worrk

Comment: But I still need to use Context.Auth.Uid because I can't hardcode the user id to the code

Comment: You mean this shouldn't be? const uid =context.auth.uid;
const user = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid)

Answer (score 0):

You don't return the promise returned by `user.get().then(...);`: your Cloud Function may be cleaned up before the asynchronous work is complete and the response sent back to the front-end.

Note that doing `doc.get().verified` is incorrect: as you will see in the [doc](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html#get), you need to pass the field path of a specific field to this method. So either you do `doc.get("verified")` or you can do  `doc.data().verified`;.

Therefore the following should work:

```
exports.checkVerification = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated');
    }
    console.log('user is ', context.auth.uid);
    const user = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.auth.uid);

    return user.get().then(doc => {

        console.log('data read');
        if (doc.get("verified") {
            console.log('verified');
        } else {
            console.log('not verified');
        }
        return "success";
    }).catch(error => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal');
    });
});
```

---

In addition, note that you may throw an error if the user document does not exist and return a specific error to the front-end, i.e. not the generic `internal` one (maybe `not-found`, see the [list of possible codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#functionserrorcode)).

Comment: I didn't suggest use doc.get().verified. Please see my code posted. doc.get() returns promise and we should use data() to reach values of doc. I have been using these for my last projects.

Comment: @development-ninja I didn't write that you suggested to use `doc.get().verified` :-) I actually interpreted your answer as pointing out that doing `doc.get().verified` is incorrect. Sorry for that, if it was not the case. I'll remove any mention of your answer.

Comment: @DininduPerera Hello, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen, on occasion, that information coming in to the function via context and data are actually JSON, and not *strictly* a standard Javascript object.  In a similar issue of matching (in my case, a customClaim on the context.auth.token), I had to do something like:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context.auth.token.customCLaim))
```

They *behave* like an object (i.e. I can call/assign context.auth.token.customClaim), but results from a console.log are different.

```
console.log(context.auth.token.customCLaim);
//prints {"userID": "1234567890"}

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context.auth.token.customClaim)));
//prints {userID: "1234567890"}
```

Subtle, but it tripped me up in a few authentication cases.